# How to get a dynamic property in Jenkins Groovy DSL

Tags: jenkins, groovy, dsl

Please read the comments to understand the problem.

```
job(buildV2PerfTest) {
    displayName('Performance Test')
    steps {

        //I am loading a value into a properties file using the shell command. The name of the variable is callbackUrl
        shell('echo "callbackUrl=http://`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname`:8080" > env.properties')

        //then I add the propeties file to Jenkins properties
        environmentVariables {
            propertiesFile('env.properties')
        }
        maven {
            goals('-P performance test')
            //I want to pass to maven a loaded property here
            property('callbackUrl', "${callbackUrl}")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I compile this code it says that the property does not exists. Indeed. It will exist when I trigger the job. I want to know how to reference dynamic properties.

P.S.
The [documentation](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.toplevel.EnvironmentVariableContext.propertiesFile) tells how to load the variables, but fails in explain how to access them

Comment: Have you tried `build.environment.get("callbackUrl")`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
property('callbackUrl', "\$callbackUrl")
```